# Any good explanation of the different weapons and their effect on Sins of a Solar Empire?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire

I regularly play SoaSE but one thing that I haven't found is a good explanation/tutorial of the differences between the weapons present in the game and their effect on the hull and shield points of the enemy ships.

Any good pointers?

Answer (score 5):

If you Google [Sins of a Solar Empire wiki](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&source=hp&q=Sins+of+a+Solar+Empire+Wiki&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CnuOTd7pFTPLCCZHuzASZtMWiCgAAAKoEBU_QYJ8A&fp=1) there a quite a few fan made wikis that could hold the information you seek.

**Update:** Found this google [spreadsheet](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AjoM84CpClJ7cDd4Y19zbmQ5Q2MtNm8yVXd2UEVXVWc&gid=0).  Probably as good as you are going to get.

Comment: I haven't found anything related to the question on those wikis, can you point the exact link you were referring to? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did the spreadsheet help?

Comment: Certainly it helped but, my question is. Why do exists laser, phase missiles and autoguns? Only for aesthetic purposes or they deal different damage against different enemies? And in the same vein, 100 shield points are equivalent absorbing damage than 100 hull points?

Answer (score -1):

i don't know about the two, but phase missiles do phased damage, meaning it may overpass the shield and directly damage the hull of a ship. also, i think autoguns are for TECS only. will check later when i get home.